# How to access Sinatra's params in helpers?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper

How can I access Sinatra's `params` hash in a custom helper?

E.g.:

```ruby
# in app/helpers/my_helper.rb
module MyApp
    module MyHelper
        def self.test ()
            params.inspect
        end
    end
end

# in app.rb
helpers MyHelper
test_result = test # undefined method `params' for MyApp:Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need `self` for helpers:

```
module MyApp
    module MyHelper
        def test()
            params.inspect
        end
    end
end
```

Note that the helper is only available in the request context (i.e. during the processing of a request):

```
get '/' do
  test_result = test
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was using `self` because I had different apps mounted at different routes, but sharing common elements like views and helpers. According to the initial set up, helpers were inaccessible in sub-apps, so I had to use `MyApp::MyHelper::test()`. After rearranging how apps are mounted, your answer worked.

Answer (score -4):

Replace `params.inspect` with `params[:inspect]`. This should work.

Comment: the error clearly says `params` is not defined. changing the method called on it is not going to change the result.

Comment: Neeraj T, I'm not trying to access a value stored in the `params` hash; rather, trying to call the `inspect` method on it. As maček pointed out, the error has to do with `params` not being accessible at the helper level.